# Метабагтрекер локализации, ошибки не относящиеся к уже существующим строкам в переводе

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

> ## Вопрос закрыт. Для новых сообщений об ошибках локализации создавайте новые вопросы — по одному на ошибку или страницу, объединяющую несколько ошибок.

Перенсу ка я свой старый тред из старой меты в новую на всякий случай, а то в нем 4 голоса и он утонул. Некоторые баги еще актуальны.

1. **(частично закрыто)** Новые картинки, но все равно одна фраза на английском осталась. Станиц для 404 ошибки и остальных HTTP ошибок нет в переводе.
2. **(закрыто)** В профиле пользователя вместо картинки с метой почему-то alt текст "favicon веб-сайта meta профиль на мете"
3. **(закрыто)** Баннер справа Looking for a job на главной(`div id="hireme" class="blue looking tagged"`). Нет строк.
4. Внизу в футере список других сайтов SE. Он разбит на категории(Technology, Life/Arts, Culture/Recreation и.т.д). Сами названия сайтов конечно нет смысла переводить, но категории можно, но их тоже нет.
5. Если нажать на аватар пользователя в хедере, placeholder окна поиска "поиск" исчезнет и текст изменится на "user:%номер%". Этой строки нет в переводе.
6. **(частично закрыто. Знак "Дисциплинированный" все еще ломает верстку в Firefox.)** Название значка больше 17 символов ломает всю верстку в окне с их описанием. Самый большая проблема "Общественное воздействие". Оно даже загораживает описание. Кроме него еще 6 других слишком длинных названий значков. Надо менять их.
7. "What's your software or hardware question? be specific."(`span class="edit-field-overlay"`). Появляется при попытке задать новый вопрос как плейсхолдер в текстовом окне с заголовком. Нет в переводе. В мете тоже самое только другая непереведенная фраза.
8. В той же форме желтый баннер справа(`div id="sidebar" class="ask-sidebar"`), опять нет строк.
9. **(закрыто)** В заголовке раздела описания значков слишком длинная панель. Опять испорченная верстка. [Справочный центр > Знаки Все Заработанные ....](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) должна быть одна строчка а не две.
10. **(закрыто)** Справка переводится на старой мете. `div id="sidebar" class="faq-page"` в этом диве есть ссылки("Спрашивая, наша модель, репутация и модерация, моя учетная запись, ответить") на разделы справочного центра которых вообще нет в переводе, они ведут на пустые страницы. Это желтый баннер, появляется справа при нажатии кнопки "Значки" на главной. Надо либо делать перевод всей справки(это лишняя работа). Либо просто убрать ссылки.
11. **(закрыто)** Не все темы визиток есть в переводе. Отсутствуют темы default clean dark. Тема hotdog есть и переведена как союзная(она красная и это круто). Они внутри безымянной таблицы в диве `div id="mainbar-full" class="user-show-new"`. Чтобы попасть туда нужно зайти в анкету и нажать ссылку визитка.
12. **(закрыто)** https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/helper/stats к этой форме нет строк для баннера справа и основной фразы "Help and Improvement". `div class="stats-sidebar"`
13. **(частично закрыто)**. В мете не наблюдается. Самый омерзительный баг верстки в футере. Самая первая строчка: "тур справка блог чат данные соглашение политика конфиденциальности". Там должна быть одна строка, а не "оставить отзыв" на второй строке.  Нужно срочно сократить политику конфиденциальности и остальные слова. `div class="top-footer-links"`.
14. **(закрыто)** Обновили верстку вопросов на нулевой в Firefox+BSD.(До этого я фиксил её сменой масштаба текста до 90%). Спасибо, молодцы, читают багтрекер. И еще один странный баг, заголовок вопроса в основном списке вопросов на главной верстается неправильно. Иногда он переходит на следующую строчку. [image]
15. **(закрыто)** Информация о значках/медальках не импортирована из базы ХК, информация о всех действиях пользователя наоборот импортирована. В результате в текущей альфа версии нельзя получить значок за первую правку или голос(скрипт считает что я уже их делал и не генерирует событие награждения). Нужно либо написать скрипт пересчета медалек либо импортировать их из ХК.
16. **(закрыто)** Машинный перевод справки по Markdown. Я уже сделал его нормальным, но его все еще [нужно заревьювить](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ru/viewstrings/#ru/english/40264472?user=igumnov&reviewed=no).
17. **(закрыто)**. Такая фича, видимо нельзя самому утверждать, нужно чтобы кто-нибудь другой просмотрел. Сделайте это кто-нибудь с 2к+ кармы. Спасибо @Barmaley. Не работает правка описания меток. Сделал хорошую статью про С по метке "c". Однако скрипт почему-то говорит что я не могу утвердить его, хотя кармы достаточно.
18. Значок "Бета" получить невозможно. Все условия давно выполнены, но скрипт почему-то не выдает его. Не уж то он выдается вручную и нужно ждать фактического завершения беты?

<s>Добавляйте сюда остальные отсуствующие строки, сломанную верстку и.т.д.
У меня довольно редкий браузер BSD+Firefox. Chrome+Win7 верстает лучше однако некоторые баги (9) проскакивают и там. В оригинальном SE все работает нормально в обоих случаях.</s>

Не добавляйте сюда баги, создавайте новые вопросы.

Comment: 101 репутация..

Comment: Что такое значок "бета"?

Comment: 14 пофиксили наконец, спасибо ребята.  13 и 7, 8 добить бы еще, остальные не так критичны.

Comment: @igumnov: В списке https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ru/viewstrings/#ru/english/40264472?user=igumnov&reviewed=no нет больше ни одного вопроса.

Comment: @VladD Спасибо, обновил.

Comment: Все, последний критичный баг с формой отправки ответов (7,8) был закрыт. Спасибо всем кто учавствовал в исправлении того что было в этом списке. Тему считаю закрытой.

Comment: 7 и 8 вчера починили.

Comment: 5 – так и должно быть, это синтаксис поиска.

Answer (score 6):

Ошибки в формах множественного числа на главной странице:

[image: ошибка локализации №1]   (исправлено)
[image: ошибка локализации №2]   (исправлено)
[image: ошибка локализации №3]   (исправлено)
[image: ошибка локализации №4]

Поскольку все три правильные формы присутствуют на странице, проблема должна быть в движке:

- для чисел от 10 до 19 (а также 110-119, 210-219 и т. д.) не должно применяться правило выбора формы мн. ч. по последней цифре,
- отрицательные числа должны браться по модулю, а
- для сокращённых форм наподобие 2K подходит лишь форма «много».

---

Обновление: кажется, форма на «11» сейчас правильная, но 12, 13 и 14 всё ещё неправильно.

---

Обновление: проблема с 12-14 и отрицательными числами, кажется, решена. Осталась проблема с сокращениями.

Comment: Добавил в базу дефектов.

Comment: Проглядел первый раз. Занес новый дефект. Спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Текст "Вопрос был удалено" появляется в верхней плашке при написании ответа, если в этот момент вопрос был удалён. Возможно, есть аналогичные баги в локализации других сообщений, появляющихся в этой плашке, однако, из-за спцифичных условий её появления они пока не были замечены.

[image]

Странные комментарии о удалении и восстановлении сообщения пользователем, его опубликовавшим, в [истории правок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/425000/revisions).

Answer (score 3):

Ещё один странный баг (Win7/Firefox, английский и русский, если важно). Время, когда был задан вопрос, меняет отображение с нормального на сокращённое. Воспроизводится так:

1. Заходим на страницу https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

[image: вид вначале]

2. Дожидаемся, пока произойдут какие-то изменения, появится кнопка «X вопросов с изменениями»:

[image: кнопка обновления появилась]

3. Нажимаем на кнопку, получаем другие строки:

[image: после обновления]

Если обновить страницу, снова получаем отображение как в п. 1.

Answer (score 2):

у меня несколько вопросов.

во-первых, кнопку обратной связи разместите заметнее.

ну и пара ошибок:

> [image: введите описание изображения здесь]

почему текст не на русском языке?

---

> [image: введите описание изображения здесь]

---

соответственно, "связаться с нами" пропадает из виду.

браузер - фф

Answer (score 2):

Небольшие ошибки на странице https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges:

[image: удалени]

В слове «удаление» заблудилась одна буква «е». А из первого слова сбежала одна «н»: «Расширен_ое».

Защищённые вопросы имели дыру в безопасности и с буквы «ё» украли точки.

Comment: Это до сих пор не исправлено. Не могли бы вы опубликовать это отдельным вопросом? Тогда шансы будут выше.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Не вопрос :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Создал: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2403/10105

Comment: спасибо, плюсанул )