# Долгосрочные цели для сообщества StackOverflow на русском языке

Tags: обсуждение, stackoverflow

Предлагаю обсудить долгосрочные цели, которые стоят перед сообществом StackOverflow на русском языке.

### Список заявленных предложений

- [Довести показатель отвеченных вопросов за всё время до 85%.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/956/181472)
- [Создание справочного центра.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/981/181472)
- [Улучшить перевод движка.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/980/181472)
- [Создать FAQ по Stack Exchange](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/982/181472) (Создан: [Часто задаваемые вопросы о Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/983/))

### Предложение

Формат — по аналогии с уже имеющимся вопросом «[Какие изменения необходимы Stack Overflow на русском?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/594/181472)». Отличие — в том, что там в основном предлагаются изменения, близкие к [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), то есть требующие (после обсуждения) изменений движка, правил, содержимого сайта.

Здесь же предлагаю обсудить те изменения, которые требуют активных скоординированных действий сообщества. Всё, для чего недостаточно усилий одного человека, что не имеет готового автоматизированного решения.

**Предлагаю здесь оценивать и уточнять постановку цели**, а не достижимость или способы достижения. Как обычно, нравится — за, не нравится — против. В комментариях — мнения по поводу уточнения сроков. Для координации действий по достижению давайте использовать отдельные вопросы и чат(ы).

### Формат:

#### Цель / Задача

Краткая формулировка.

#### Обоснование

Зачем это нам нужно. Какие возможности открывает? Какую более крупную задачу помогает решить?

#### Критерии.

Четкие и измеримые критерии выполнения. Например, определенные показатели статистики по запросу в SE Data Explorer.

#### Срок

Хотя бы приблизительный срок выполнения.

#### Ссылки

На отдельный вопрос или вопросы, в которых обсуждаются способы решения задачи, либо которые имеют отношение к теме.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Цель / Задача

Создание справочного центра.

#### Обоснование

Текущий справочный центр Stack Overflow на русском имеет два важных недостатка.

1. Практически все публикации были написаны переводчиками, которые мало представляют, что такое Stack Overflow, да и программирование  в целом. Читать такую справку сложно. Ко всему, хоть текст и является переводом, но суть может быть потеряна.
2. Все публикации - это переводы правил действующих в сообществе Stack Overflow на английском. Хотя всеобъемлющие цели сообществ абсолютно одинаковые (создание свободно распространяемой базы прикладных знаний и коллективная помощь), но все же, некоторые правила, и тем более формулировки самих правил, могут отличаться (вспомним перевод слова "flag").

Сам процесс я бы предложил построить на базе общих вопросов. Раз в неделю будет публиковаться одна статья справочного центра в исходном или улучшенном варианте. Любой желающий может вносить правки в течении двух недель. По прошествии указанного срока, обновленный раздел публикуется в справочном центре.

#### Критерии

*Минимально*: проверить и при необходимости улучшить все уже существующие страницы справочного центра.

*Оптимально*: минимальный критерии, а также добавить новые правила, так чтобы любой спорный момент можно было решить обратившись к справочному центру.

#### Срок

Программу минимум, на мой взгляд, можно решить к концу декабря 2015. Уверен, новые правила будут создаваться в течении всей жизни сообщества.

#### Ссылки

Отчасти, новые правила можно черпать из вопроса ["Какие изменения необходимы Stack Overflow на русском?"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/594/). Сообщество уже создало одну прекрасную страницу справочного центра - [Обсуждение раздела справки "На какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы?"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/107/).

#### Ссылки на обсуждения разделов справочного центра

- [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be) [Правка раздела “Что означает статус вопроса “закрыт” или “ заморожен”](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1064/).
- [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be) ["Что такое общие сообщения?"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/948/6).
- [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be) ["Дополнительный раздела справки Будьте дружелюбными"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/928/).
- [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be) [Редактирование раздела справки «Как выполнять поиск?»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1018/6).
- [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be) [Улучшение страницы справки «Что такое Мета и как она работает?»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1148/).
- [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be) [Редактирование раздела «Какой тип вопросов лучше не задавать?»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1259/).
- [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be) [Редактирование раздела «Можно ли ответить на свой вопрос?»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1373/).
- [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be) [Редактирование раздела «Инструменты модератора»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1617/6).
- [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be) [Улучшение содержимого «Как создать краткий, завершенный и достоверный пример»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2780/).
- [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be) [Улучшение перевода «Какое поведение ожидается от участников?»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2492/).

Comment: Предлагаю следующим пунктом (или внеочередно, работы немного) откорректировать справку по поиску: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/806/181472

Comment: [Опубликовал](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1018/6) улучшеный вариант справки по встроенному поиску.

Comment: Дал ссылку на этот ответ в описании метки [meta-tag:справка]: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/133

Comment: Спасибо! Отличные описания!

Comment: О, а я и забыл, что тут есть общий список со статусами. Может, перенести это в отдельный вопрос? Будет проще отслеживать.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Да, скорее всего, вы правы. Было бы хорошо вынести список в отдельный вопрос. При публикации следующего улучшения так и поступлю (либо вы можете сделать это уже сейчас). Спасибо!

Comment: вообще, этот вопрос и http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/594/ показали, что списки задач неэффективны. Должен быть отдельный вопрос на каждую задачу. Вот тут пресловутые 85% затмевают три остальных задачи, которые не мене важны.

Comment: Напоминание: при переносе вопроса обязательно обновить ссылку в описании метки: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0/info

Comment: Закреплю эту как самую актуальную на данный момент.

Answer (score 19):

#### Результат.

Сообщество успешно завершило бету в декабре 2015. На момент аттестации показатель отвеченных вопросов был 82%.

---

#### Цель

Довести показатель отвеченных вопросов *за всё время* до 85%.

#### Обоснование

Статистика отвеченных вопросов — один из необходимых критериев для аттестации сайта. (Однако, он не является единственным или достаточным.)

Это основной показатель, по которому мы сейчас не дотягиваем до нужного уровня по критериям Area 51.

[StackOverflow на португальском на момент выхода из беты имел 85% отвеченных](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23539/stack-overflow-in-portuguese).  Остальные показатели у SO.PT были ниже, [чем у нас](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41168/stack-overflow-in-russian). Это создает прецедент (других сайтов *StackOverflow*, вышедших из беты, пока что нет). Предполагаю, что и для нас этот показатель является целевым.

Работа возможна в следующих направлениях:

- Закрывать старые *неотвечаемые* вопросы ([они удаляются и уходят из статистики](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392/181472)).
- Отвечать на старые отвечаемые, либо находить и поднимать существующие ответы
- Повышать качество новых вопросов
- Повышать отвечаемость новых вопросов

#### Критерии.

- Общее количество вопросов на сайте ∑:  [`is:question`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%20is%3Aquestion)
- Группа A: вопросы, не имеющие ответов вообще. [`is:question isanswered:no answers:0`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion%20isanswered%3Ano%20answers%3A0)
- Группа B: вопросы, не имеющие ни принятого ответа, ни ответа с положительной суммой голосов. [`is:question isanswered:no answers:1.. hasaccepted:no`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion%20isanswered%3Ano%20answers%3A1..%20hasaccepted%3Ano)

Нужно, чтобы `(A + B ) / ∑ ≤ 0.15`.

#### Статистика

Перенесена в отдельный вопрос: [Статистика отвеченных вопросов и актуальные задачи](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1339/181472)

#### Срок

Как насчет конца декабря 2015 года? Давайте подарим себе на новый год выход из беты. Думаю, можно будет заранее договориться с администрацией и обсудить другие важные критерии (и если будут, поставить по ним отдельные задачи).

#### Ссылки

- [Как считается статистика отвечаемости вопросов на Area 51?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/807/181472)
- [Некоторые цифры по ru.SO](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/875/181472)
- [Автоматическое удаление заброшенных вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392/181472)
- [Что такое “бета”?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-beta)
- https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/

Comment: *Нужно, чтобы (A + B ) / ∑ ≤ **0.25*** — как я понимаю, это текущее состояние. а нужно, всё-таки, что-то в райне `≤ 0.15` (т.е., `≥ 85% отвеченных`).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: исправил.

Comment: Добавьте, что ли, заодно и сколько надо на сейчас, например, вопросов ответить, чтобы цель выполнить)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб: Поскольку ответ получил поддержку сообщества, через пару дней распишу подробно предложения и опубликую отдельным документом.

Comment: (1) нужно подчеркнуть, что следует избегать бездумного удаления старых вопросов то есть  следует удалять только те вопросы без ответов, которые бы были удалены даже если бы они были заданы сегодня. Иначе, это напоминает ужасы советской плановой экономики, когда оборудование уничтожалось, чтобы манипулировать показатели, спущенные сверху. (2) Может быть стоит более агрессивные настройки (больший процент) для уже существующего алгоритма, который неотвеченные вопросы поднимает, включить.

Comment: (3) людей, которые на вопросы отвечают каждую неделю не так много ([`~60`](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/875/23044)). Можно прикинуть насколько реалистична цель. Сколько в среднем сейчас одобренных ответов в день ([за июль ~1800 ответов, то есть ~60 в день](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aanswer%20score%3a1%20created%3a2015-07..2015-07))? Сколько нужно ответов в день, чтобы новогодней цели достичь? ([за июль ~2200 вопросов](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+closed%3Afalse+created%3A2015-07..2015-07))

Comment: @jfs: спасибо, это важный акцент. Полностью согласен, что нельзя закрывать ради закрывания. Когда-то еще в чате avp подчеркивал, что это может привести нас к тому же, что случилось с СССР. Думаю, нужно будет отдельно об этом написать еще.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, а разве при подсчёте не надо добавлять в запрос условия типа: `closed:no`, `duplicate:no` и, может быть, ещё что-то в этом духе?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: Не представляю себе, считает ли Area51 закрытие и дубли. Надо бы выяснить.

Comment: Очень много вопросов не имеющих ни одного ответа - на самом деле отвечены в комментариях к вопросу, и довольно часто даже самим автором. Как быть с такими вопросами? Я на парочку повесил тревогу, но общее решение пока непонятно.

Comment: @LbISS: Вот, что надо делать: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/441697/181472 http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/441695/181472

Comment: @NickVolynkin для начала надо отучить отвечающих [отвечать в комментариях](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/441834/). а то рука устанет за ними подчищать. такое ощущение что на HC было нормой ответить комментом и пойти дальше.

Comment: @PashaPash: да уж, есть такая проблема.

Comment: @PashaPash [Это было не нормой, а одной из острейших проблем](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/419/).

Comment: возможно, имеет смысл упомянуть про поисковый тэг `intags:mine` — чтобы можно было сосредоточиться лишь на вопросах, имеющих [избранные метки](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: отличная идея. Вот соберусь с духом — напишу детальный пост про работу с вопросами, обязательно включу вашу рекомендацию.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin каждый четверг — рубрика "Как наши дела на Area51". ))

Comment: @NickVolynkin, лучше всех! ничего, что я влез «попэрэд батьки»?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: как раз хорошо, а то я забыл обновить. Пускай у рубрики будут два ведущих )) Вообще, пора бы делать следующий шаг, а то этот вопрос уже даже из блока популярных ушел.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: обновил рубрику. Похоже, мы ускоряемся даже.

Comment: Во, как раз хотел запросить данные по скорости и ускорению) Самому мне лень считать - может добавите в тело ответа?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб: данные по скорости и ускорению есть в новом вопросе: [Статистика отвеченных вопросов](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1339)

Comment: @NickVolynkin Декабрь 2015 наступил, бета закончилась. Обновите ответ или удалите

Answer (score 8):

#### Цель / Задача

Улучшить перевод движка.

#### Обоснование

Сообщество уже достаточно хорошо потрудилось над созданием перевода сайта. Текущее качество можно охарактеризовать как "сносное", но на мой взгляд, перевод еще не дотягивает до статуса выхода из беты. Мы легко можем найти большое количество недочетов, например, во многих местах встречается строка вида

> Stack Overflow на русском Q&A for программистов

Спешу предложить цель поиска дефектов локализации, создания базы этих дефектов и дальнейшего их устранения.

#### Критерии

К сожалению, четкие критерии выработать крайне сложно (хороший перевод - очень относительная характеристика). Наиболее простой в этом случае выход, создать вопрос, где ответами будут дефекты. Задача будет считаться выполненной как только все упомянутые проблемы будут решены.

#### Срок

Наиболее оптимальный строк - конец сентября.

#### Ссылки

Некоторые проблемы уже известны.

- [Дефекты локализации обновлённого профиля](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/201/).
- [Метабагтрекер локализации, ошибки не относящиеся к уже существующим строкам в переводе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/20/).

Comment: Базу дефектов создавать на Мете или отдельный багтрекер завести?

Comment: На каком шаге перевода сейчас наиболее острые проблемы? (1) [непереведённых или неутверждённых строк](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/51109179?reviewed=no&translated=no) не так много (я не замечаю на сайте таких строк) (2) Знают ли посетители сайта, что на Мете можно об ошибках перевода сообщать? (на сайте есть средства, чтобы внимание привлечь)  (3) [Открытых багов по локализации немного](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F+bug+-status-completed)

Comment: (4) скрытые ошибки: плохой перевод препятствует тексту эффективно выполнять его задачу (посмотреть на google analytics, есть ли неожиданные шаблоны поведения посетителей сайта) (5) Мне кажется лучше разделять разные ошибки перевода в разные сообщения, чтобы можно было обсуждать и голосовать за возможные решения

Comment: @NickVolynkin На мой взгляд, практичнее на Мете.

Comment: "Создать вопрос, где ответами будут дефекты. Задача будет считаться выполненной как только все упомянутые проблемы будут решены" - это задача про Ахиллеса и черепаху.

Answer (score 6):

#### Цель / Задача

**[Часто задаваемые вопросы о Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/983/)**

На основе ранее заданного вопроса: [Нужно ли переводить или формировать FAQ for Stack Exchange sites?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/668/)

Составить собственный сборник часто задаваемых вопросов, по аналогии с [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/296059)

- Упорядоченный
- Полный, насколько это возможно
- Регулярно обновляемый

Акцент на том, что это **документация от Сообщества** StackOverflow на русском языке. Именно усилиями сообщества этот документ наполняется и поддерживается, и мы все несем ответственность за его качество.

**Формат:** Вопрос с упорядоченным списком, где каждый пункт — ссылка на другой вопрос на Мете.

#### Дополнительная задача

Выработать правила наполнения списка. Явным образом описать требования к качеству, которым должен соответствовать вопрос для его внесения в список.

#### Обоснование

На Мете задается много хороших вопросов и даются хорошие, исчерпывающие ответы. Некоторые из них содержат важные знания о том, как устроен Stack Exchange и как им пользоваться.

Раздел справки слишком мал, чтобы вместить все-все вопросы, особенно не самые часто задаваемые или предназначенные для более опытных пользователей.

Нужно создать общую «точку входа» для всех этих вопросов. Одна страница, которую можно будет добавить в закладки или в избранное.

#### Критерии.

1. Полнота.

   - Все ценные вопросы — в списке.
   - Все важные темы — закрыты, т.е. есть соответствующий написанный с нуля или переведенный документ.
2. Упорядоченность.

   - Систематизированный список.
   - Есть критерии качества для faq-вопроса.
3. Обновление.

   - Отлажена система обновления списка. (На Meta SE это делается через метку faq-proposed.)

#### Срок

Первая версия документа должна появиться до 10 августа 2015 (выполнено).

К 31 декабря 2015 документ должен соответствовать формальным критериям качества.

#### Ссылки

- [Часто задаваемые вопросы о Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/983/)
- [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)
- [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)

Comment: На мой взгляд, задача очень-очень актуальная с точки зрения [tag:faq]-вопросов не Меты, а основного сайта, то есть документации по базовым областям знаний. Например, ["Книги по C# и другая литература"](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: А конкретнее? Собрать все вопросы по name-faq в одно оглавление? Или сделать список книг и другой литературы по каждому языку и технологии?

Comment: Цель в том, чтобы публиковать такие вопросы. Это позволит: 1) решить проблему многих новичков, 2) ссылать на такие вопросы в случае появления аналогов, 3) создать действительно качественный источник общих знаний для освоения профессии. Список таких вопросов можно посетить либо в описание метки (выглядит лучше), либо отдельной публикацией.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/git-add/info , там есть список — это похоже на то, что вы предлагаете?

Comment: Да, именно! Чем больше будет [tag:faq]-вопросов, тем быстрее будет изучение конкретной технологии.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: меня только смущает, что у описания метки 25 просмотров за месяц. Маловато это.