# Правка раздела "Что означает статус вопроса “закрыт” или “заморожен”"

Tags: поддержка, статус-завершено, правила, справка

Правка раздела справочного центра ["Что означает статус вопроса “закрыт” или “ заморожен”? Почему часть вопросов находится в состоянии “заморожено”?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

---

**Заголовок**

> Что означает статус вопроса «закрыт» или «требует правки»? Почему некоторые вопросы «требуют правки»?

---

**Публикация**

#### Почему некоторые вопросы «требуют правки»?

Вопросы, [не соответствующие тематике сайта](/help/on-topic) или критериям качества, могут быть отмечены как «требующие правки» опытными участниками сообщества. На вопрос «требующий правки» нельзя опубликовать ответ, но можно внести улучшающую правку, чтобы в дальнейшем открыть его повторно.

Вопрос автоматически попадает в очередь на повторное открытие, если в течении пяти дней с момента получения статуса «требующий правки», он был улучшен. Если вопрос не был открыт повторно в течение пяти дней, его статус изменяется с `[требует правки]` на `[закрыт]`.

Каждый закрытый или требующий правки вопрос сопровождается пояснением, которое помогает автору (и другим участникам сообщества) понять, что именно следует сделать для того, чтобы вопрос был открыт повторно.

Причины закрытия вопросов.

- **[дубликат](/help/duplicates)** - основной целью закрытия является сбор всей информации относящийся к вопросу в одном месте.

> Такой вопрос задавали ранее и на него уже получен ответ. Если представленные ответы не являются исчерпывающими, пожалуйста отредактируйте этот вопрос, пояснив, в чем состоит его отличие, или задайте новый вопрос.

- **[не по теме](/help/on-topic)** - каждое сообщество само решает, какие вопросы допустимы, а какие - нет.

> Скорее всего, данный вопрос не соответствует тематике сайта, согласно правилам описанным в справке.

Если вы полагаете, что при другой формулировке вопрос может соответствовать тематике, возможно, стоит отредактировать вопрос или оставить комментарий с предложениями по его улучшению.

- **необходимо уточнить подробности вопроса** - иногда сообществу требуется больше информации, чтобы помочь вам в решении вашей проблемы.

> Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример кода.

Отредактируйте ваш вопрос, чтобы он как можно более конкретно описывал то, что вы пытаетесь решить. Пожалуйста, не забудьте ответить на все комментарии, оставленные другими участниками.

- **необходимо конкретизировать вопрос** – если для ответа на ваш вопрос требуется написать целую книгу или существует множество верных ответов, он, скорее всего, не соответствует формату вопросов и ответов.

> В текущем виде на ваш вопрос невозможно дать лаконичный ответ. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, какие технологии используете и что хотите видеть в ответе.

- **необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать однозначно верный ответ** – [обсуждения, основанные на различных мнениях](/help/dont-ask) – это прекрасно, но они тоже с большой вероятность не подходят для формата вопросов и ответов.

> Вопрос порождает бесконечные прения и дискуссии, основанные не на знаниях, а на мнениях. Для получения ответа перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначно правильный ответ, либо удалите вопрос вовсе.

#### Кто может отметить вопрос как требующий правки?

В день, участники с репутацией $ReputationRequiredToClose и более могут голосовать до $CloseVotesPerDay раз за закрытие вопросов. Если вопрос получает $CloseVotesNeededForClosure голосов за закрытие, его статус изменяется на `[требует правки]`. Эти же участники могут проголосовать за повторное открытие вопроса таким же способом. Каждый участник может отдать всего один голос за закрытие или повторное открытие одного вопроса. (Например, если вы проголосовали за закрытие вопроса, который затем был закрыт, а после повторно открыт, вы не сможете еще раз проголосовать за его закрытие).

Модераторы могут закрывать и открывать вопросы без голосования.

Пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с разделом [«Что делать, если я не согласен с закрытием вопроса? Как его снова открыть?»](/help/reopen-questions) для получения подробной информации о повторном открытии вопросов.

#### Почему часть вопросов помечена как «закрытые»?

Автор вопроса отмеченного как `[требующего правки]` имеет возможность внести улучшающую правку в течении пяти дней. Если вопрос отмеченный как `[требующий правки]` будет улучшен автором, он автоматически попадет в [очередь проверок](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work), в которой он может быть открыт повторно. Если вопрос не был открыт повторно в течение пяти дней, состояние `[требует правки]` автоматически изменяется на `[закрыт]`. Функциональной разницы между состояниями `[требует правки]` и `[закрыт]` нет; в обоих состояниях на вопроса нельзя дать ответ, но можно комментировать, голосовать и редактировать.

Comment: охохо, я еще не добрался до справки по поиску) Пожалуйста, не спешите ее публиковать.

Comment: Как договаривались, раз в неделю!

Comment: я там хочу не только форматирование поправить. Есть некоторые недокументированные особенности параметров поиска. Считаю, нужно написать про них. Но это небыстрая работа, нужно все сочетания перепроверить. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297958/2790048