# Улучшение страницы справки "Что такое Мета и как она работает?"

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, справка

Предлагаю улучшение перевода страницы справки "[Что такое Мета и как она работает?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)".

---

### Что такое Мета и как она работает?

Мета $SiteName  – это сайт, где участники обсуждают технические и организационные аспекты работы сайта $SiteName. Мета отделена от главного сайта, чтобы сократить информационный шум на основном ресурсе, и одновременно обеспечить подходящее место для вопросов о том как и почему $SiteName работает так, а не иначе. Мета предназначена для:

- **...общения участников $SiteName друг с другом** - для вопросов о том, как работает сайт, о правилах поведения и решениях принятых сообществом;
- **...общения участников $SiteName с компанией Stack Exchange** - для сообщений о дефектах или предложений по улучшению сайта и правил сообщества;
- **...общения компании Stack Exchange с сообществом** - обратная связь по новым идеям или функционалу, обсуждения правил поведения, и других вопросов влияющих на жизнь сообщество.

На Мете приветствуются любые вопросы каким-либо образом касающиеся $SiteName. Перед тем как задавать ваш вопрос, пожалуйста, [выполните поиск](/search), убедившись, что он не задавался ранее.

Не задавайте вопросов, которые не имеют отношения к $SiteName или, как минимум, к сети Stack Exchange. Это не площадка для обсуждения всевозможных тематик, а место для улучшения жизни нашего сообщества и сайта в целом.

#### Голосование на Мете отличается

Как и любой другой сайт сети Stack Exchange, Мета позволяет участникам голосовать за или против вопросов и ответов. Для большинства сообщений голоса отражают пользу: хорошо написанные, обоснованные и продуманные получают больше внимания и положительных отзывов. Сообщения, за которые часто голосуют и на которые часто ссылаются, могут в дальнейшем стать частью [управляемого сообществом FAQ](/q/983/) или страниц [Справки](/help).

*В отличие* от «обычных сайтов» сети Stack Exchange, Мета позволяет сообществу обсуждать, аргументировано спорить, предлагать изменения жизни самого сообщества и работы программного обеспечения. **Для сообщений, обозначенных как «[предложение](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)», голосование обозначает согласие (одобрение) или несогласие** с предлагаемым изменением, а не качество или пользу самого сообщения.

#### Есть учётная запись на $SiteName, есть и на Мете

На Мете $SiteName не требуется создавать отдельную учетную запись. Как только вы зарегистрировались на $SiteName, у вас автоматически появляется учётная запись на Мете $SiteName.

Голосования на Мете не влияют на вашу репутация на основном сайте, а репутация на Мете соответствует вашей репутации на $SiteName. Общаясь на Мете, вы можете получить дополнительные знаки. Для участия в обсуждениях на Мете вам необходимо иметь $Privilege-ParticipateInMeta баллов репутации.

#### Обязательные метки

На главном сайте мы рекомендуем не использовать [мета-метки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1160).

Мета отличается от основного сайта и предназначена совершенно для других задач. Пожалуйста, используйте для каждого публикуемого вопроса как минимум одну из следующих мета-меток:

- `[support]`, которая означает запрос поддержки по какому-либо функционалу сайта;
- `[bug]`, означающая повторяющуюся проблему на сайте, которая, скорее всего, происходит из-за дефекта в программном обеспечении.
- `[feature-request]`, предназначенная для предложений нового функционала или запроса изменения существующего.
- `[discussion]`, предназначенная для вопросов, когда вы не уверены в правильности той или иной позиции или для субъективных вопросов. Если вопрос не является сообщением о дефекте или предложением нововведения, вероятно, это обсуждение.