# Что-такое мета-метки?

Tags: поддержка, faq, метки, справка, мета-метки

Здесь будет перевод текста https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/ и ещё немного слов о том, почему мета-метки — это плохо. Пока что это будет вопрос-заглушка, чтобы можно было добавить ссылку в редактируемый раздел справки: [Улучшение страницы справки "Что такое Мета и как она работает?"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1148/181472)

*(в работе)*

Comment: работа затянулась? :-D

Comment: Привет из 2018-го!

Comment: @Grundy и почему я не удивлён.

Comment: @Arhad привет из конца 2018.

Answer (score 6):

## Смерть мета-меток

На Stack Overflow есть несколько меток, которые долгое время раздражали меня:

- [subjective](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subjective)
- [best-practices](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/best-practices)
- [beginner](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beginner)

Но я никогда не мог чётко сформулировать, что именно не так с ними. С течением времени меня это беспокоило всё больше и больше. 
Настолько, что около двух месяцев назад (Июнь 2010) я был вынужден спросить на мете: [Должны ли мы навсегда удалить метку [subjective]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51627/should-we-permanently-remove-the-subjective-tag)?

Есть несколько слабых аргументов в пользу сохранения [subjective](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subjective). Аргументы против намного сильнее. [Shog9 лучше всего описал ситуацию](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/51627/should-we-permanently-remove-the-subjective-tag/51644#51644):

> Думаю, [subjective](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subjective) в лучшем случае бесполезна, а в худшем несёт вред.
>
> Бесполезна, т.к. эта метка ничем не помогает при фильтрации в силу своей, в общем-то, субъективности. Я могу сказать, что такое [pool](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pool), [faq](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq), [list](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list), но где граница **субъективности** я не могу ответить.
>
> Вредна, т.к. есть пользователи, которые всерьёз думают, что, как и wiki, это своего рода магия, позволяющая игнорировать стандарты написания постов.
>
> Метка использовалась без какой-либо реальной последовательности в течение долгого времени. Пора отпустить её и идти дальше.

Всё изменилось, когда я увидел этот совершенно [блестящий пост от Aaronut на meta.cooking](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/434/please-zap-the-meta-tags-and-dependent-tags). Проблема и её решение стали окончательно понятны:

> В последнее время наблюдается большой всплеск меток, которые бесполезны и просто вредят. Я хочу подчеркнуть, что они обычно добавляются с хорошими намерениями, и я не сомневаюсь в мотивации авторов таких меток. Но эта конкретная категория меток вызывают массу проблем.
>
> **Причина проблем в том, что такие метки не описывают *содержание* вопроса**. Они описывают какой-то другой аспект вопроса, например, уровень авторского мастерства или мотивацию автора, или вообще описывают "вид" вопроса (опрос, руководство и т. д.).
>
> Мета-метки, на самом деле, являются подмножеством большей проблемы, которую я обычно называю "зависимыми метками". Это метки, которые ничего не говорят сами по себе - вы не можете сказать, о чем идет речь в вопросе, если они не сопряжены с какой-либо другой меткой (или несколькими из них). Эти метки являются проблемой, т.к. люди этого не понимают и часто используют их как единственную метки вопроса.

Это понимание, которое ускользало от меня в течение двух последних лет. Кажется очевидным в ретроспективе, не так ли?

## С этого момента мета-метки не в почёте.

Как наверняка сказать, используете ли вы мета-метку? Очень просто.

1. **Если метка не можем работать *самостоятельно*, вероятно, это мета-метка.** Каждая используемая вами метка должна быть более-менее самостоятельной. Мета-метки вроде [beginner](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beginner), [subjective](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subjective),  [best-practices](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/best-practices) бесполезны сами по себе - они не говорят ничего про сущность вопроса.
2. **Если метка для разных людей означает разное, то это, вероятно, мета-метка.** Иронично, что смысл [subjective](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subjective) сам по себе...субъективный. То же самое относится и к [best-practices](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/best-practices), [beginner](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beginner). Лучшие практики [для кого](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/04/best-practices-and-puffer-fish.html)? Новичок по каким [критериям](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/10/defending-perpetual-intermediacy.html)? Эти метки невозможно определить никакими объективными метриками. Для сравнения, метки [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), [javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) кристально чисты для всех, кроме самых сумасшедших.

Рад сообщить, что с сегодняшнего вечера мы систематически уничтожали наиболее распространенные мета-метки: [beginner](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beginner), [subjective](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subjective), [best-practices](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/best-practices) на Stack Overflow, Server Fault и Super User.

И знаете что? Это хорошо. И это правильно.

Я виню нас за то, что позволили этим меткам появиться в ранний период жизни Stack Overflow. Нам следовало бы искоренить их на раннем этапе, чтобы был прецедент. Обнадёживает то, что мы можем учиться на экспериментах на [зарождающихся Stack Exchange 2.0 сайтах](http://stackexchange.com/). Нет причин, по которым эти сайты должны повторять ошибки, которые мы совершили в отношении меток два года назад, - мы можем совершенствоваться каждый раз для каждого нового сообщества и привносить эти улучшения во всю сеть.

Пока, мета-метки.

(отдельное спасибо [Aarobot](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/141911/aarobot) и [Shog9](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) за их фидбек за последние годы и, в частности, в этом топике и на мете в целом).