# [Очень-длинно-именуемое-тестирование]

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, метки

С метками про тестирование есть проблема. Хотелось бы перевести англоязычные названия на русский либо просто создать метки и добавить их к соответствующим вопросам. Но нормальные названия превышают **25 символов — допустимый предел названия метки:**

- [функциональное-тестирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) 27
- [регрессионное-тестирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) 26
- [интеграционное-тестирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) 27
- [автоматизация-тестирования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f) 26

Что с ними делать? Я пока что склоняюсь к варианту «тесты».

- [функциональные-тесты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b)
- [автотесты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b) и т.п.

Comment: Тесты? Если эта хрень каким-то чудом скопмилировалась, уже хорошо. Запустилась? Просто прекрасно.

Comment: @igumnov: ага, называется «дымовое тестирование». Включили в розетку, дым идёт? Нет? Странно, но хорошо.

Comment: честно говоря, не вижу большой проблемы

Comment: @NickVolynkin не совсем в розетку - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_testing_(mechanical)

Comment: @PashaPash да это какие-то шутники в википедии навандалили!

Comment: @Etki действительно, котиков же в статье нет :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Увеличили лимит символов для задания метки до 30 символов. Спасибо за предложение!

Comment: Пока что ложная тревога. Длинна жестко задана в базе за счет размера поля. Проблема в процессе обсуждения.

Comment: Теперь должно работать.

Comment: Завершено - значит, повысили лимит?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Именно так. Сейчас лимит должен быть установлен в 30 символов.

Comment: Тестировщики довольны, [a программистам не хватает](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5546/178988).

Answer (score 2):

"Честно говоря, не вижу большой проблемы"

Метки названы адекватно. Да, русский язык длинный. В чем именно проблемма длины меток более 25 символов? )

Comment: Нельзя создать метку длиной более 25 символов.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Ограничения это хорошо, но нельзя грести все языки под 1 линейку, и делать 25 символов и на китайский и на русский. Можно ли как-то поднять лимит до 30 например?

Comment: надо бы выяснить.

Comment: Проблема и правда в лимите. 25 символов не выглядит адекватно. Ничего, вот немецкая и финская локализации подтянутся ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю подождать пока по этим меткам наберется достаточно много вопросов, и выбрать наиболее популярный вариант. Я сомневаюсь что наберется хотя бы десяток вопросов по регрессии. Нет вопросов - нет меток - нет проблемы.

Кроме того, предлагаемые метки [регрессионное-тестирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) и [автоматизация-тестирования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f) явно являются метаметками, т.к. включают в себя сразу несколько независимых подходов к тестированию. Метаметки - [это плохо](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1160/) и создавать их не стоит.

Comment: По ним не может быть вопросов, так как их нельзя создать.

Comment: @NickVolynkin я имел ввиду не метки, а именно исами вопросы, например, о регрессионном тестировании - те вопросы на которые вы эти метки собираетесь ставить.  Такие вопросы вообще есть на сайте?

Comment: все тесты на [tag:selenium], [tag:selenium-webdriver] по сути своей являются функциональными или интеграционными, хотя реализуются на фреймворках юнит-тестирования.

Comment: а все [tag:юнит-тесты], [tag:unit-testing] используются для регрессионного тестирования.

Comment: @NickVolynkin ...потому что фремворки юнит-тестирования ничем особо не приспособлены именно к юнит-тестам. это просто способ вызвать кусок кода.

Comment: это очень удобный способ вызвать кусок кода )

Comment: @NickVolynkin если все более-менее автоматические тесты с вашей точки зрения - это регрессионное тестирование, то метка регрессионное-тестирование - метаметка, и она не нужна

Comment: @NickVolynkin то же самое - метки автотесты, интеграционное-тестирование - метаметки. вместо них стоит использовать или метку конкретного инструмента (selenium) или метку конкретного вида тестирования (юнит-тесты)

Comment: нет, далеко не все. Юнит-тесты автоматизированы по своей природе. А вот более высокие уровни как раз автоматиризуются отдельными усилиями и это почва для вопросов. Функциональные, интеграционные, нагрузочные.

Comment: @NickVolynkin тем не менее - если автотесты, регрессионное-тестирование - это несколько разных видов тестирования - то это по определению метаметка. метаметки не нужны.

Comment: хм, об этом нужно подумать.

Answer (score -5):

можно сокращать слова. например:

- `функциональное-тестир-ние` 25

Comment: Это будет выглядеть, как паршивый конспект паршивой лекции.