# В статье справки про метки поменять ссылку на статью про мета-метки

Tags: дефект, локализация, метки, справка

В статье справки [Что такое метки и как их использовать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) ссылка ведёт на [The Death of Meta Tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно заменить ссылку на наш перевод: [Что-такое мета-метки?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1160/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8).

Comment: Имхо, достаточно было убрать хвост с id из ссылки при правке.

Comment: @älёxölüt ЧПУ ссылки же ^^"

Comment: Ну он вряд ли нужен для ссылок, которые и так обрамлены.

Comment: @älёxölüt ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: [Или вовсе так](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1160/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4)