# Объединить метки [проект] и [project]

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю объединить метки [проект](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82) и [project](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project), так как они являются тем же самым только на разных языках. В качестве основной предлагаю сделать русскоязычную метку.

---

*Дополнительна информация о метках:*

- метка [проект](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82) - 28 вопросов, описание метки отсутствует;
- метка [project](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project) - 30 вопросов, описание метки отсутствует;

---

*Update:*

Добавил краткое описание русскоязычной метке, на случай если метки останутся.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю сжечь данные метки, так как видятся мне совершенно безликими и ничего не добавляющими к контексту вопроса. Любая программа может быть рассмотрена как какой-то проект или его часть вне зависимости от целей (учебная программа → учебный проект, научная программа → научный проект, медицинская программа → медицинский проект и т.д.). Крайне похожи данные метки на метаметки.

Если данное предложение получит достаточную поддержку, то, возможно, имеет смысл добавить данные метки в чёрный список.

Comment: Про такой вариант я тоже думал, хорошо что ты написал об этом.

Comment: Ну да, типичные бесполезные мета-метки, которые нужно выпиливать  https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8328/15479