# Как отнестись к меткам [анимация] и [анимации]?

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, метки

Вопрос: как отнестись к меткам [анимация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f) (1314 вопросов) и [анимации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8) (11 вопросов)?

### Варианты:

- разделить на простые(например,сдвинуть прямоугольник) и сложные анимации(например, [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1429589/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-tkinter))
- сделать синонимами
- разделить по-другому

Comment: + за Синоним....

Comment: + за Разделить на простые и сложные анимации

Comment: «простые» и «сложные» это слишком субъективная оценка, такое разделение не имеет практического смысла

Comment: Там всего 11 вопросов...

Comment: В идеале нужно выпилить обе, т.к. метаметки не нужны: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1160/1365. Уж точно не нужно разделять как-то по-другому, все равно получатся метаметки.

Comment: Я бы явно не хотел чтобы удаляли тег `анимация`. Особенно при создании игр - это одно из первых с чем возникает кучу вопросов. Вот на вебе 95% этих вопросов, сводятся к стилям CSS, потому там это может и не несёт никакого смысла, но в целом она полезна - как по мне

Comment: @EzioMercer так вопросы никуда не денутся, и отсутствие специального тега никак не помешает.

Comment: @insolor Не, я понял, что только тег пропадёт, но он мне не кажется мета тегом. Т.е. я его могу вполне себе использовать как самодостачтоный тег. Хотя скорее всего я бы в заголовке уже упомянул бы слово "анимация" какая бы с ним проблема не была и остался бы тег допустим "разработка игры".... Хмм, может ты и прав, наеврное можно удалять :)

Comment: Он не может быть самодостаточным тегом, только вместе с другими тегами (например, программой для анимации или языком программирования, или библиотекой). При этом, например, сама по себе программа для анимации может быть самостоятельным тегом, и тег "анимация" уже будет излишним, и так понятно, что это по сути про анимацию.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: скриншот]

```
updating post history, 13 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 10 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 7 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'анимации': [анимации] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 1325
tag remapping of [анимация] and [анимации] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
1 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
```

Comment: А почему удаляется из 10-ти вопросов и добавляется к 7-и? Разве не все `анимации` должны смениться на `анимация`

Comment: @EzioMercer, видимо на оставшихся трёх стояли оба тега одновременно.