# Другой участник испортил вопрос

Tags: обсуждение

Мне поставил дизлайк и испортил метки [другой участник](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/1365/insolor) [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1429589/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8). Точно надо что-то с этим делать.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Как отнестись к меткам анимация и анимации?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12066/1365)

Comment: Во-первых, дизлайки правилами не запрещены. Во-вторых, то что я убрал метку "анимации" и добавил метку "tkinter", не портит ваш вопрос никаким образом.

Comment: Даже наоборот, если посмотреть [историю правок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1429589/revisions), то можно увидеть, что это вы постоянно портите метки, убирая все метки кроме вашей любимой "анимации"

Comment: В-четвертых, есть мнение, что [мета-метки не нужны](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1160/Что-такое-мета-метки) (и "анимация", и "анимации" являются мета-метками). Если же есть желание использовать такую метку, лучше использовать метку с "анимация", которая используется в 1300 тысячах вопросов, а не ее дубликат "анимации", которая используется в ~10 вопросах.

Comment: Метка [tag:анимации] не лишняя. Она отражает смысл вопроса. А метка [tag:tkinter] лишняя.Можно её заменить на  [tag:анимация].

Comment: Рекомендую почитать справку по меткам: [Что такое метки и как их использовать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). После этого уже возвращаться к дискуссии

Comment: "А метка tkinter лишняя.Можно её заменить на анимация." - вообще конечно интересная позиция. У вас в коде используется tkinter, значит с целью категоризации вопросов стоит добавить соответствующую метку, благодаря этому на вопрос обратят внимание участники, подписанные на эту метку. Уж точно метки "tkinter" и "анимация" не взаимозаменяемы.

Comment: Как добавление новых меток может испортить вопрос? Чем больше меток, тем больше людей обратят внимание. Вот вы [tag:python] не добавили, я ваш вопрос пропустил

Answer (score 4):

1. "Мне поставил дизлайк другой (конкретный) участник" - откуда такая информация? К чему необоснованная клевета?
2. "испортил метки другой участник" - чем? Тем что конкретизировал ваш вопрос? Тем что благодаря нужным и дополнительным меткам ваш вопрос увидят больше людей? В чём порча?

Comment: Открою секрет: за дизлайки вопросов не снимается репутация, только за дизлайки ответов.

Comment: @insolor Вот не надо было открывать этот секрет

Comment: Уточнил, т.к. минусы могут ставить именно только участники.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос 

Comment: @АлексейШиманский У меня тут было целое расследование, где я показывал, что первый пункт ничем не обоснован (в истории можешь посмотреть), а потом открыли секрет и я удалил это всё 

Comment: Да, это я видел)  Поэтому это теперь просто комментарии с вопросами))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Ну пусть останется тут, всё равно удалится вопрос :) (надеюсь)

Comment: Тем более, что метка "обсуждение"