# Синонимизация меток об исходном коде

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть такие метки:

- [исходный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9) (1 вопрос)
- [source-code](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/source-code) (2 вопроса)
- [source](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/source) (6 вопросов)

Надо бы их синонимизировать/объединить.

Comment: А смысл создавать синонимы, если так мало вопросов, и метки все равно мусорные? Первая метка явно создана ошибочно. Также, как я уже писал ранее, к темам о добавлении синонимов нужно обоснование.

Comment: Насколько я вижу, сейчас нет ни одного вопроса в указанных метках.

Comment: Так пришел insolor и все метки (справедливо) удалил )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Удалил все перечисленные метки из вопросов. "source" кое-где использовалось как обозначение тега `<source>`, но я не вижу смысла для каждого html тега или например для каждой функции или класса qt добавлять отдельную метку. Можно было бы "source" оставить, но ее бы все равно продолжали бы использовать для вопросов по исходному коду.

---

Если это действительно нужно, теперь можно создать "нормальную" метку [исходный-код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4). Нужно ли - интересный вопрос. Без пояснений это похоже на [мета-метку](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1160/1365). С другой стороны, можно было бы ее использовать для вопросов по поиску исходного кода или сборки из исходников. Как вариант, для поиска исходников, можно создать конкретную метку [поиск-исходного-кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0) по аналогии с поиском библиотек, но довольно длинно получается.

Comment: [tag:поиск-исходного-кода] в принципе может пригодиться. Отмечать вопросы про сборку из исходников мне кажется бесполезным - на 20% вопросов её можно автоматом навесить, и она не будет иметь никакой описательной силы - слишком общее понятие. Кстати, это же по сути [tag:компиляция] (556 вопросов)?

Comment: @Kromster про сборку из исходников я имею в виду <s>пропатчить KDE</s> [собрать Qt из исходников](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1223229/1365) и подобные вопросы. Я такие вопросы не уж часто встречаю, вот 250 штук нашел: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%B8%D0%B7+%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2, возможно по вариации запроса еще что-то найдется. Но опять же, не факт что отдельная метка для этого случая так уж нужна.