# Надо ли объединять [большие-числа]?

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть такие вот метки:

- [biginteger](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/biginteger)
- [bigdecimal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bigdecimal)
- [большие-числа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0)

Надо ли их синонимизировать? Похоже, что тут [большие-числа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0) - общая для двух других.

Comment: bigdecimal и biginteger это разные понятия, и разные вопросы могут быть с ними связаны. Я думаю, объединять не нужно.

Comment: Я думаю, что не стоит.

Comment: @wchistow А вы разве не можете предлагать синонимы метки прямо на странице синонимов метки? Вроде как да

Comment: @PetLinux для предложения синонимов нужно иметь рейтинг по метке 5+

Comment: @PetLinux, это можно делать только с репутацией 2.5k+

Answer (score 4):

Думаю, [большие-числа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0) надо синонимизировать с [длинная-арифметика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0).

А вот [biginteger](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/biginteger) и [bigdecimal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bigdecimal) - это его подразделы о целых числах и десятичных дробях - их надо оставить. Хотя я бы их всё-таки через дефис написал...

---

```
updating post history, 26 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 23 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 23 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'большие-числа': [большие-числа] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 48
tag remapping of [длинная-арифметика] and [большие-числа] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
1 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
```

Comment: Так почему бы не синонимизировать сейчас?

Comment: @maestro, готово.

Comment: [статус-завершено]?

Comment: @Danis, но ведь сделано не то, что в вопросе? Может [статус-отклонено]?

Answer (score 1):

- [bigdecimal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bigdecimal) - это про класс [java.math.BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). 16 вопросов из 20 по этой метке именно про этот класс, который используется для округления чисел, не только больших. [Пример вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1278790/). А метке требуется описание.
- [biginteger](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/biginteger) - это и про [java.math.BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) ([Пример вопроса про этот класс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1227225/)), и про какие-то классы в других языках. В некоторых вопросах эту метку нужно вообще убрать, так как в вопросе имелись в виду [большие-числа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0), [пример такого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1200773/). Остальное можно не трогать.
- [большие-числа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0) - это [мета-тег](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1160/). Что такое большие числа? Какие числа являются большими? 10 - это большое число? А 100? А 1000? "Большие" - понятие субъективное. Так что его полезность вообще сомнительна, но если очень хочется, то его можно оставить, сильно он не навредит (или навредит?).

#### Вывод

Делать синонимами [большие-числа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0) и [bigdecimal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bigdecimal) **нельзя** без каких-либо сомнений. [biginteger](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/biginteger) нужно просто почистить от вопросов просто про числа, а не про какие-либо классы. И тогда выяснится, что и [biginteger](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/biginteger) **не** является делать синонимом [большие-числа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0). А [большие-числа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0) сомнительны и походят на мета-тег... Но это отдельная дискуссия.

Comment: Под большими числами часто имеют в виду реализацию чисел через длинную арифметику, и я бы сказал, что их нужно с [tag:длинная-арифметика] синонимизировать, а там где вопрос к длинной арифметике не относится - метку удалить.

Comment: А почему собственно java?

Comment: И про [tag:большие-числа] не согласен.

Comment: Да, почему только java, вот в C# тоже есть BigInteger ([System.Numerics.BigInteger](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=net-7.0))

Comment: Потому что java - язык Зонтика