# Приветствуются ли у нас метки по названию классов фреймворка Qt?

Tags: обсуждение, метки

У нас есть очень много меток по названию классов фреймворка Qt:

- [qhboxlayout](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qhboxlayout);
- [qchart](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qchart);
- [qprogressdialog](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qprogressdialog);
- [qrubberband](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qrubberband);
- [qmouseevent](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qmouseevent);
- [qmediarecorder](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qmediarecorder);
- [qtablewidget](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qtablewidget);
- [qtabwidget](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qtabwidget);
- [qtableview](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qtableview);
- [qtablewidgetitem](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qtablewidgetitem);
- [qtabbar](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qtabbar);
- ...

Большинство из них стоит только на одном вопросе.

Все они выглядят как-то подозрительно, **приветствуются ли у они нас?**

Comment: Данные метки ничего не нарушают. На этот вопрос невозможно объективно ответить.

Comment: @aepot Удивился, что на мете вообще есть такая причина закрытия. Казалось бы, есть тег `обсуждение`, и вполне нормально было бы сделать тут голосовалку, оставить теги или убрать (два ответа: "убрать" и "оставить", и т.п.).

Comment: @aepot так на мете объективные ответы и не требуются вроде?

Comment: ок, переоткрыл.

Comment: Метки с одним вопросом автоматически удаляются (https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/383139/370389), так что это не очень большая проблема.

Answer (score 3):

А что не так? Это же не [мета-метки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1160/).

- Если их используют, то они нужны. Тогда всё нормально.
- Если не используют, и они будут висеть только на одном вопросе, то они [автоматически удалятся](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12981/#comment56165_12981).