# Редактирование раздела «Можно ли ответить на свой вопрос?»

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, справка

Редактирование раздела «[Можно ли ответить на свой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)».

---

Конечно! Более того, мы [призываем](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) участников отвечать на свои вопросы. Если у вас есть вопрос, на который вы заранее знаете отличный ответ, и вы хотите поделиться своими знаниями с сообществом, то есть чтобы ваши коллеги, да и вы сами, в будущем  при возникновении аналогичной либо схожей проблемы смогли быстро найти решение, - пожалуйста, задайте такой вопрос и опубликуйте ответ.

Для публикации ответа на свой вопрос необходимо иметь 15 баллов репутации.

Чтобы опубликовать вопрос одновременно с собственным ответом:

1. нажмите на «Задать вопрос»;
2. заполните необходимые поля;
3. под полем для ввода текста вопроса отметьте галкой пункт «Ответить на собственный вопрос»;
4. в появившееся поле ввода добавьте текст ответа;
5. опубликуйте вопрос вместе с ответом.

Вы также можете в любой момент вернуться в вопрос и опубликовать решение:

- если вы нашли решение быстрее, чем сообщество;
- если вы нашли лучшее решение, чем уже предложенные;
- если ответы только подтолкнули вас к идеи реализации, а полное решение вы нашли сами.

Вы сможете [отметить ваш ответ верным](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/), через 48 часов после его публикации. Это стоит сделать, если вы нашли решение самостоятельно либо сразу опубликовали ответ. Если же один из предложенных ответов составил существенную часть итогового решения, то более правильно будет отметить этот ответ.

Пожалуйста, учтите, что принятие своего ответа не приносит репутацию и не изменяет сортировку ответов. Помните, что сообщество, возможно, сможет найти ещё более оптимальное решение вашей задачи!

Не стесняйтесь задавать вопросы, на которые знаете ответы, дополняя их решениями. Это поможет создать [свободную базу прикладных решений](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/).

Comment: Удалил прошлые комментарии. Что касается вопроса — пока не вижу даже, что бы можно было улучшить. Есть какой-нибудь вектор требуемых улучшений?

Comment: Это уже улучшенная правка исходной статьи. Можно текст переработать, вносить правки связанные с орфографией, пунктуацией и т. д. Возможно нам стоит добавить в эту статью что-то еще?

Comment: ваш вопрос про личные или общие ответы к переводам можно сюда включить в сжатом виде. Ещё есть популярный вопрос про эти самые переводы. Кстати, о переводах можно было бы и отдельным разделом запостить.

Comment: возможно, про механику зеленой галочки на самоответах можно написать.

Comment: Да, про переводы я бы тоже голосовал за отдельный раздел.

Comment: Про 48 часов, вроде сказано. Возможно что-то стоит добавить?

Comment: добавил абзац про ограничения.