# Опечатки на странице описания привилегий

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, справка

Нашел несколько опечаток на странице Справка > Привилегии > Инструменты Модератора

1. "мы рассчитываем, что вы будете помогать в управлении сообществом и служить пример."
   Должно быть "служить примером".
2. "Закрытые вопросы, не больше не имеющие ценности,"
   Должно быть "вопросы, больше не имеющие".
3. "Перед удалением посмотрите, если ли хорошие ответы на эти вопросы"
   Должно быть "посмотрите, есть ли хорошие ответы "
4. "вопрос все равно нужно удалить, не смотря на большое количество"
   Должно быть "нужно удалить, несмотря на "
5. "Смотрите также. Как работает удаление? Почему сообщения удаляются, и что это значит? По каким критериям сообщения отправляют на удаление?"
   Здесь, похоже, должны быть какие-то ссылки, но их нет.
6. В списке инструментов модерации.
   "Последние удаленные/восстановленные сообщения."
   "Сообщения, поставленные на голосование, в ожидании удаления/восстановления."
   В этих двух что имеется ввиду под "сообщения"? Везде в этом списке написано либо "вопросы", либо "ответы", а тут "сообщения"?
7. "Если отвлечься от /инструменты, в разделе /обзор можно получить доступ".
   Я не совсем понял назначение '/'.

Comment: Часть этих замечаний уже высказана здесь: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1255/181472

Answer (score 3):

Предлагаю расширенную редакцию раздела «[Инструменты модератора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)»

---

#### Что такое модерация?

Если вы являетесь одним из самых опытных участников, мы рассчитываем, что вы будете помогать в управлении сообществом и служить примером остальным.

Получив привилегию «Инструменты модераторов» вы сможете:

- просматривать удаленные сообщения;
- голосовать за закрытие и повторное открытие вопросов;
- иметь доступ к инструментам модератора;
- редактировать метки.

И, благодаря всему этому, помогать модераторам, выбранным сообществом управлять сайтом.

#### Просмотр удаленных сообщений

Привилегия предполагает доступ к сообщениям, которые были удалены авторами, участниками, с доступом к инструментам модератора или системой.

Распоряжайтесь этой привилегией с умом.

- Удостоверьтесь, что были удалены только те сообщения, *которые этого заслуживали*. Если необходимости в этом не было или более того, удаление  принесло вред, привлеките к данному факту внимание сообщества и команды модераторов.
- Отслеживайте признаки злоупотребления привилегиями, которые, возможно, были скрыты фактом удаления.
- Не злоупотребляйте данной привилегией: не надо поднимать шумиху после того, как кто-то мудро решил удалить сообщение, порождающее проблемы.

#### Удаление вопросов

Данная привилегия позволяет удалять закрытые вопросы.

#### Когда следует удалять вопросы?

Закрытые вопросы, более не имеющие ценности, стоит отмечать тревогой и затем удалять.

Перед удалением проверьте, есть ли **хорошие ответы** на эти вопросы; если есть, вопрос следует отметить тревогой как вопрос, требующий внимания модератора и подходящий для объединения. Хорошие ответы полезны даже в случае плохого вопроса и нам бы не хотелось их терять.

Будьте внимательны, удаляя вопросы, **закрытые по причине повтора**; они могут [указывать на полезные ответы](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/linking-duplicate-questions/) к другим вопросам.

Чтобы удалить закрытый вопрос, необходимо минимум 3 голоса. Однако, *количество голосов за удаление должно превосходить число голосов за вопрос и все ответы на него*.

Чтобы голосовать за удаление вопроса, необходимо подождать **2** дня с момента его закрытия. Это ограничение не распространяется на [проверенных пользователей](/help/privileges/trusted-user), если рейтинг сообщения **-3** или ниже. Если вам кажется, что вопрос все равно нужно удалить, несмотря на большое количество голосов и тот факт, что срок ожидания еще не прошел, [отметьте его тревогой](/help/privileges/flag-posts) как сообщение, требующее внимания модератора.

Вы можете просмотреть список сообщений с большим количеством голосов за удаление при помощи вкладки «удалить» [инструментов модератора](/tools?tab=delete).

#### Что происходит при удалении сообщения?

После удаления, сообщение исчезнет для всех пользователей, кроме разработчиков, модераторов и других участников обладающих необходимыми привилегиями. Однако, удаленные сообщения можно вернуть при помощи голосов за восстановление. Набравшее 3 таких голоса сообщение будет восстановлено.

Обратите внимание: «[Как работает удаление? Почему сообщения удаляются и что это значит? По каким критериям сообщения отправляют на удаление?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)».

#### Сколько раз в день можно голосовать за удаление?

Имея репутацию не менее $Privilege-ModerationTools баллов, вы можете проголосовать за удаление не более 5 раз в день. Вам будут доступны дополнительные голоса за каждые 1000 баллов репутации. В пределе, вы можете иметь до 30 голосов за удаление в день.

#### Доступ к инструментам модератора

После получения привилегии, у вас появится доступ к различным статистическим данным, которые позволят вам получить общее представлении о жизнедеятельности сообщества.

- Сообщения, набравшие максимум голосов.
- Сообщения, у которых больше всего комментариев, просмотров и правок.
- Вопросы, недавно получившие статус защищенных.
- Последние из открытых и закрытых вопросов.
- Последние перемещенные вопросы.
- Последние удаленные и восстановленные сообщения.
- Вопросы, поставленные на голосование, в ожидании закрытия и повторного открытия.
- Сообщения, поставленные на голосование, в ожидании удаления и восстановления.
- Новые ответы на старые вопросы.
- Статистика предложенных правок.
- Полная история результатов [очереди проверок](/help/privileges/access-review-queues) *всех* участников.

Чтобы получить доступ к этим инструментам, нажмите на ссылку [очередь проверок](/review) в верхней части страницы, а затем на ссылку «Инструменты» в заголовке слева.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно довольно быстро понять, что радел «[инструменты](/tools)» содержит только дополнительную *информацию*! Что с ней делать, зависит от вас: надеемся, вы являетесь участником сообщества достаточно долго, чтобы получить базовое представление о том, как должен работать сайт, и способны извлечь пользу из представленной информации. Например.

- Найдите проблему, на которую раньше не обращали внимания и, если получится, решите ее, или, если не можете справиться, то привлеките к ней внимание модераторов. [Страница статистики](/tools?tab=stats) – это золотая жила для тех, кто может извлечь пользу от капли внимания таких мудрых и опытных ветеранов сообщества, как вы.
- Найдите то удивительное нечто, за которым каждый день приходите на сайте. Страница статистики прекрасный способ это сделать.
- Можно проанализировать, чем занимаются другие участники, и, если необходимо, предложить свою помощь или поделиться советом: новые метки, новые ответы, предложенные правки, перемещенные или закрытые вопросы, удаленные сообщения... Вне раздела «инструменты», раздела «очередь проверок», можно получить доступ к полной истории действий многих других участников, если нажать на вкладку «История» в любой очереди. Такой подход также помогает выявлять проблемы сообщества.

В завершение, если вы – участник сообщества с высокой репутацией, скорее всего, коллеги будут уважать ваше мнение: если вы видите опасную тенденцию, к которой, как вам кажется, стоит привлечь всеобщее внимание, не стесняйтесь это делать – располагая большим количеством данных, будет проще обосновать собственные утверждения.

#### Встроенное редактирование меток

Теперь вы сможете редактировать метки вопросов не переходя к полной форме редактирования. Просто поместите курсор мыши рядом с линией меток, и вы увидите ссылку «редактировать метки»

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это позволяет быстро редактировать метки вопросов в случае необходимости; такая возможность будет особенно полезна в сочетании с перечнем новых меток на [странице статистики](/tools?tab=stats).

Comment: В вкладка "удалить" точно называется именно так? Если да, не переименовать ли её?

Comment: Да, проверял специально, называется «удалить». Можно переименовать «на удаление».

Comment: @Aid Кстати, [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4986/176217) уже всё есть. Я же помню, что рисовал эти картинки.

Comment: @alexolut Совершенно верно! В [справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) обновленная версия с переведенными картинками.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, а чего тогда не остановили? Спросил же специально. Я полчаса вырисовывал стрелки и склейку делал! :)