# Улучшение страницы справки «Инструменты модератора»

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, справка

Ссылка на текущую версию: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools
Название страницы: access to moderator tools
Заголовок: Access reports, delete questions, review reviews

---

#### What is moderation?

As one of our most experienced users, we're counting on you to guide the community and lead by example.

You can...

- View deleted posts
- Cast delete and undelete votes on questions
- Access moderator tools
- Edit tags inline

...which collectively allow you to help the elected community moderators in monitoring the site and helping to clean up messes.

### Viewing deleted posts

You now have privileged access to posts that have been removed, either by their authors, by users with access to moderator tools, by moderators, or by the system.

Use this privilege wisely:

- Make sure what is being deleted *should have* been deleted, and bring unnecessary or harmful deletions to the attention of the community and/or moderator team.
- Watch for signs of abuse being obscured by deletion.
- Don't abuse this privilege to stir up trouble when someone has wisely decided to remove a problematic post.

You also have a new search operator available to find your own deleted posts: `deleted:1`.

### Deleting questions

Users with this reputation level can delete closed questions.

#### When should I delete questions?

Closed questions that are of no lasting value whatsoever should be flagged and deleted.

Before voting to delete, please check whether there are **any good answers**; if so, then the question should be flagged for moderator attention as a potential merge candidate. We don't like to lose great answers!

Also, be cautious when deleting questions closed as **duplicates**; [they can serve as a signpost](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/linking-duplicate-questions/), directing users to useful answers on another question.

It takes **3** votes, minimum, to delete a closed question. However, the number of delete votes required scales to the number of votes on the question and all its answers.

You must wait for a question to be closed for **2** days before you can vote for deletion. This restriction is removed for [trusted users](/help/privileges/trusted-user) when a post scores **-3** or lower. If you feel a post should be deleted despite having lots of votes or for being new, please [**flag** it](/help/privileges/flag-posts) for community moderator attention.

You can view a list of posts with outstanding delete votes via the [moderator tools delete tab](/tools?tab=delete).

#### What happens when a post is deleted?

Once a post has been deleted, it will disappear for all users except developers, moderators, and other fellow users with this privilege. However, deleted posts can be undeleted by casting undelete votes. Once a post has **3** undelete votes, it will no longer be deleted.

See also: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

#### How many times can I vote to delete per day?

At $Privilege-ModerationTools reputation, you can cast 5 delete votes per day. An additional vote is granted per 1000 reputation, to a maximum of 30 delete votes per day.

### Access moderator tools

You now have access to various lists and statistical reports, giving you a broad overview of activity on the site:

- Posts with extreme votes
- Posts with the most comments/views/edits
- Recently protected questions
- Recently closed/reopened questions
- Recently migrated questions
- Recently deleted/undeleted posts
- Questions with pending close/reopen votes
- Posts with pending delete/undelete votes
- New answers to old questions
- Suggested edit stats
- The full history of reviews by *all* users in any [/review queue](/help/privileges/access-review-queues)

Access these tools by clicking the [review](/review) link in the top bar, and then the Tools link in the header:

[image: Tools | Review]

If you poke around in /tools, you'll quickly notice that most of what's found there isn't directly actionable - it's *informational!* What you *do* with that information is up to you: hopefully, you've been around long enough now that you have some idea of how you want the site to be run, and are able to make good use of the information presented. For instance:

- Find problems that've been overlooked and fix them if you can, or bring them to the attention of the moderators if you can't. The [stats page](/tools?tab=stats) is a gold mine for outliers that might benefit from a bit of attention from a wise, aged site veteran such as yourself.
- Find awesome stuff that reminds you of why you like coming here. The stats page is a good one for this too.
- Sanity-check the stuff that other people are doing, and offer guidance and correction where necessary: new tags, new answers, suggested edits, questions being migrated or closed, posts being deleted... Outside of /tools, you also get a full history of actions taken by others in /review by clicking the history tab in any queue, which can be helpful in identifying problems there as well.

Finally, as a high-reputation member of the site your opinions likely carry quite a bit of weight with your peers: if you see a trend that you think is worth calling attention to, don't hesitate to do it - having access to more data makes it easier to back up your assertions.

### Inline tag editing

Finally, you now have the ability to do inline tag edits on questions. Hover your mouse next to the tags and you should see a "edit tags" button:

[image: Inline tag edits]

This allows you to quickly retag questions that need it, which you'll find especially useful combined with the list of new tags on [the stats page](/tools?tab=stats).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Название страницы: Инструменты модератора

Заголовок: Доступ к статистике, удалению и очереди проверок

---

#### Что такое модерация?

Если вы являетесь одним из самых опытных участников, мы рассчитываем, что вы будете помогать в управлении сообществом и служить примером остальным.

Получив привилегию «Инструменты модератора» вы сможете:

- просматривать удалённые сообщения;
- голосовать за закрытие и повторное открытие вопросов;
- иметь доступ к инструментам модератора;
- быстро править метки.

И, благодаря всему этому, помогать модераторам, выбранным сообществом, управлять сайтом.

#### Просмотр удалённых сообщений

Привилегия предполагает доступ к сообщениям, которые были удалены авторами, участниками, с доступом к инструментам модератора или системой.

Распоряжайтесь этой привилегией с умом.

- Удостоверьтесь, что были удалены только те сообщения, *которые этого заслуживали*. Если необходимости в этом не было или более того, удаление принесло вред, привлеките к данному факту внимание сообщества и команды модераторов.
- Отслеживайте признаки злоупотребления привилегиями, которые, возможно, были скрыты фактом удаления.
- Не злоупотребляйте данной привилегией: не надо поднимать шумиху после того, как кто-то мудро решил удалить сообщение, порождающее проблемы.

#### Удаление вопросов

Данная привилегия позволяет удалять закрытые вопросы.

#### Когда следует удалять вопросы?

Закрытые вопросы, более не имеющие ценности, стоит отмечать тревогой и затем удалять.

Перед удалением проверьте, есть ли **хорошие ответы** на эти вопросы; если есть, вопрос следует отметить тревогой как вопрос, требующий внимания модератора и подходящий для объединения. Хорошие ответы полезны даже в случае плохого вопроса и нам бы не хотелось их терять.

Будьте внимательны, удаляя вопросы, **закрытые по причине повтора**; они могут [указывать на полезные ответы](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/linking-duplicate-questions/) к другим вопросам.

Чтобы удалить закрытый вопрос, необходимо минимум 3 голоса. Однако, *количество голосов за удаление должно превосходить число голосов за вопрос и все ответы на него*.

Чтобы голосовать за удаление вопроса, необходимо подождать **2** дня с момента его закрытия. Это ограничение не распространяется на [проверенных пользователей](/help/privileges/trusted-user), если рейтинг сообщения **-3** или ниже. Если вам кажется, что вопрос всё равно нужно удалить, несмотря на большое количество голосов и тот факт, что срок ожидания ещё не прошёл, [отметьте его тревогой](/help/privileges/flag-posts) как сообщение, требующее внимания модератора.

Вы можете просмотреть список сообщений с большим количеством голосов за удаление при помощи вкладки «удалить» [инструментов модератора](/tools?tab=delete).

#### Что происходит при удалении сообщения?

После удаления сообщение исчезнет для всех пользователей, кроме разработчиков, модераторов и других участников, обладающих необходимыми привилегиями. Однако, удалённые сообщения можно вернуть при помощи голосов за восстановление. Набравшее 3 таких голоса сообщение будет восстановлено.

Обратите внимание: «[Как работает удаление? Почему сообщения удаляются и что это значит? По каким критериям сообщения отправляют на удаление?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)».

#### Сколько раз в день можно голосовать за удаление?

Имея репутацию не менее $Privilege-ModerationTools баллов, вы можете проголосовать за удаление не более 5 раз в день. Вам будут доступны дополнительные голоса за каждые 1000 баллов репутации. В пределе, вы можете иметь до 30 голосов за удаление в день.

#### Доступ к инструментам модератора

После получения привилегии, у вас появится доступ к различным статистическим данным, которые позволят вам получить общее представлении о жизнедеятельности сообщества.

- Сообщения, набравшие максимум голосов.
- Сообщения, у которых больше всего комментариев, просмотров и правок.
- Вопросы, недавно получившие статус защищенных.
- Последние из открытых и закрытых вопросов.
- Последние перемещённые вопросы.
- Последние удалённые и восстановленные сообщения.
- Вопросы, поставленные на голосование, в ожидании закрытия и повторного открытия.
- Сообщения, поставленные на голосование, в ожидании удаления и восстановления.
- Новые ответы на старые вопросы.
- Статистика предложенных правок.
- Полная история результатов [очереди проверок](/help/privileges/access-review-queues) *всех* участников.

Чтобы получить доступ к этим инструментам, нажмите на ссылку [очередь проверок](/review) в верхней части страницы, а затем на ссылку «Инструменты» в заголовке слева.

[image: img]

Можно довольно быстро понять, что раздел «[инструменты](/tools)» содержит только дополнительную *информацию*! Что с ней делать, зависит от вас: надеемся, вы являетесь участником сообщества достаточно долго, чтобы получить базовое представление о том, как должен работать сайт, и способны извлечь пользу из представленной информации. Например.

- Найдите проблему, на которую раньше не обращали внимания и, если получится, решите её, или, если не можете справиться, то привлеките к ней внимание модераторов. [Страница статистики](/tools?tab=stats) – это золотая жила для тех, кто может извлечь пользу от капли внимания таких мудрых и опытных ветеранов сообщества, как вы.
- Найдите то удивительное нечто, за которым каждый день приходите на сайт. Страница статистики прекрасный способ это сделать.
- Можно проанализировать, чем занимаются другие участники и, если необходимо, предложить свою помощь или поделиться советом: новые метки, новые ответы, предложенные правки, перемещённые или закрытые вопросы, удалённые сообщения... Вне раздела «инструменты», раздела «очередь проверок», можно получить доступ к полной истории действий многих других участников, если нажать на вкладку «История» в любой очереди. Такой подход также помогает выявлять проблемы сообщества.

В завершение, если вы – участник сообщества с высокой репутацией, скорее всего, коллеги будут уважать ваше мнение: если вы видите опасную тенденцию, к которой, как вам кажется, стоит привлечь всеобщее внимание, не стесняйтесь это делать – располагая большим количеством данных будет проще обосновать собственные утверждения.

#### Встроенная правка меток

Теперь вы сможете быстро править метки вопросов не переходя к полной форме редактирования. Просто поместите курсор мыши рядом с линией меток, и вы увидите ссылку «править метки».

[image: img2]

Это позволяет быстро редактировать метки вопросов в случае необходимости; такая возможность будет особенно полезна в сочетании с перечнем новых меток на [странице статистики](/tools?tab=stats).