# Опечатка: пропущено "з" в слове "раздел" в описании привилегий за 10k

Tags: дефект, локализация, справка, 10k-tools

> Можно довольно быстро понять, что **радел** «инструменты» содержит только дополнительную информацию!

[link](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)

Comment: Вот [здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4985/176217) пытались улучшить. Вроде модератор может поправить эти страницы.