# Улучшение перевода «Какое поведение ожидается от участников?»

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, справка

Ссылка на текущую версию: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

---

Заголовок: Какое поведение ожидается от участников?

---

Мы крайне рады видеть вас на сайте! Мы просим всех участников соблюдать ряд правил при использовании сайтов сети Stack Exchange.

#### Будьте честны

Прежде всего, будьте честны. Если вы видите заведомо неверную информацию, [голосуйте против](/help/privileges/vote-down). Добавляйте [комментарии](/help/privileges/comment), в которых поясняйте, в чем именно видите проблему. Публикуйте правильные ответы. Также, что не менее важно, [вносите улучшающие правки](/help/privileges/edit) в существующие вопросы и ответы! Таким образом, мы сможем сделать Stack Exchange лучшим местом для хранения знаний.

В дополнение к вышесказанному мы просим вас соблюдать следующие правила:

#### Будьте дружелюбными

Отвечая на вопросы или щедро делясь своими знаниями, помните, что все мы здесь, чтобы вместе учиться чему-то новому. Будьте доброжелательны и терпеливы, особенно с теми, кто может знать меньше, чем вы. И не забудьте про чувство юмора, так, на всякий случай.

Подробное руководство см. в разделе «[Будьте дружелюбными](/help/be-nice)».

#### Не используйте подписи, статусы и приветствия

Каждое ваше сообщение уже «подписано» вашей визиткой участника, которая ведет напрямую на страницу вашей учётной записи. Если вы используете дополнительную подпись или статус, он будет удален, чтобы сократить информационный шум в вопросах и ответах.

Страница вашей учётной записи принадлежит вам — на ней можно разместить информацию о ваших интересах, ссылки на проекты, над которыми вы работали и много другой информации, которой вы хотите поделиться!

#### Избегайте чрезмерной саморекламы

Сообщество чаще всего голосует против саморекламы и отмечает такие сообщения как спам. Создавайте хорошие и релевантные ответы и если часть из них (но не все) будут касаться вашей продукции или сайта, никто не будет возражать. Пожалуйста, учтите, что вы обязаны сообщать о вашей заинтересованности в ваших ответах.

Если в большинстве ваших сообщений упоминаются ваша продукция или сайт, возможно, вы занимаетесь не теми делами и не в том месте. Расценки на рекламу довольно гуманные; подробнее о возможности размещения рекламы можно узнать в [отделе по продаже рекламы](http://stackexchange.com/about/contact). Также мы предлагаем [бесплатные рекламные объявления](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/) в сообществе для проектов с открытым кодом и для некоммерческих организаций.