# «Q&A for программистов»

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, целевая-аудитория

Страница моих аккаунтов в сети Stack Exchange — **http://stackexchange.com/users/7696365/%d0%a1%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%b0-%d0%a7%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85?tab=accounts**.

Скриншот:

[image: Страница аккаунтов]

`Q&A for программистов` и `Q&A for лингвистов, этимологов, и энтузиастов русского языка`. Полагаю, лучше заменить `for` на `для`.

[**Здесь**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/980/199934) упоминалось о данном дефекте:

> Мы легко можем найти большое количество недочетов, например, во многих местах встречается строка вида
>
> ```
> Stack Overflow на русском Q&A for программистов
> ```

Но, как видно, он не устранён до конца.

Comment: Ещё бы Q&A в В&О.

Comment: Об этом уже известно на [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286603/339911).

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Целевая аудитория сайтов Stack Exchange](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3680/%d0%a6%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-stack-exchange)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема исправлена (вероятно могло бы быть и лучше):

> [image: ruSO]
>   [image: rusSE]