# Ошибки перевода на странице описания привилегий

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, нет-в-transifex

Небольшие ошибки на странице https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges:

[image: удалени]

В слове «удаление» заблудилась одна буква «е». А из первого слова сбежала одна «н»: «Расширен_ое».

Защищённые вопросы имели дыру в безопасности и с буквы «ё» украли точки.

---

Вопрос был уже задан [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1986/10105), но проблема не была решена. Поскольку старый вопрос «расформирован», переношу это багрепорт сюда.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Опечатка в справке на странице описания привилегий](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2181/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b9)

Comment: @VenZell: Тут отмечена одна ошибка, про которую у вас не сказано ))

Comment: @NickVolynkin да, в чате разобрались